# Docker issue commands to an app inside container?

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I am using `nodeBB` to start a server you can run `./nodebb start` to stop you can do `./nodebb stop`. Now that I have dockerized it http://nodebb-francais.readthedocs.org/projects/nodebb/en/latest/installing/docker/nodebb-redis.html I am not sure how I can interact with it.

I have followed the steps "Using docker-machine mac os x"

```
docker run --name my-forum-redis -d -p 6379:6379 nodebb/docker:ubuntu-redis
```

Then

```
docker run --name my-forum-nodebb --link my-forum-redis:redis -p 80:80 -p 443:443 -p 4567:4567 -P -t -i nodebb/docker:ubuntu
```

Then

```
docker start my-forum-nodebb
```

I had an issue with redis address in use, so I want to fix that and restart but I am not sure how? Also I would like to issue the command `grunt` in the project directory, again not sure how?

My question is how can I interact with an app inside a docker container as if I had direct access to the project folder itself? Am I missing something?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23716211/connecting-to-a-running-docker-container-differences-between-using-ssh-and-run might help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All code in this answer is untested, as I'm currently at a computer without docker.

#### See whether the containers are still running

```
docker ps
```

#### Stop misconfigured containers

```
docker stop my-forum-redis
docker stop my-forum-nodebb
```

#### Remove misconfigured containers and their volumes

(The docker images they are based on will be retained.)

```
docker rm --volumes --force stop my-forum-nodebb
docker rm --volumes --force my-forum-redis
```

#### Start again

Then, issue your [3 commands](http://nodebb-francais.readthedocs.org/projects/nodebb/en/latest/installing/docker/nodebb-redis.html#usage) again, now with the correct ports.

#### Execute arbitrary commands inside container

> Also I would like to issue the command grunt in the project directory, again not sure how?

You probably want to do the following after the `docker run --name my-forum-nodebb ...` command but before `docker start my-forum-nodebb`.

`docker run` accepts a command to execute instead of the container's default command. Let's first use this to find out where in the container we'd land:

```
docker run my-forum-nodebb pwd
```

If that is the directory where you want to run `grunt`, just go forward with it:

```
docker run my-forum-nodebb grunt
```

If not, you'll have to stuff several commands into a single one. You can do that by invoking a shell:

```
docker run my-forum-nodebb bash -c 'cd /path/to/project/dir; grunt'
```

where `/path/to/project/dir` is to be replaced by where you want to run `grunt`.

Comment: Very nice, thank you so much for you time and effort. I will try this and chime in with the result I am sure it works flawlessly :)

Comment: Some of the commands might need some tweaking to actually work. Also, some depend on the particulars (especially entrypoints) of the used images not being too non-standard, which I didn't verify yet.